# NetBeans number of swing items

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I'm using NetBeans to create a cardlayout to collect and show product information.  So far all has been working fine but now when I come to add another swing component ie JTextField or JButton I get the following error when I run it.

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Is it possible NetBeans has a limit on the number of swing components it can handle or is the error for some other reason?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you don't have a class with a `main()` method that can be used to run your program

Comment: So how come I only get this error now, it been working fine for several months as I develop the panels.  It now just errors when I add a new component but not if I swap one!

Answer (score 0):

**no there is no limit on the number of components.**

probably your program doesn't have main method or Main class, or your project run configurations are wrong.

check if you have no Main class and main method add one to your project like below:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new YourFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

or check project run configurations:

**in netbeans 8.0.2**
`Select your project` > `Right click on it` > `Click on Set Configuration` > `Select Customize...`

now in left menu (categories) select **`Run`** then type the name your main class in `Main Class:` textfield. 
[see this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAjee62LXa_QnNFTlZSc0ZiOHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The project is 
public class MainJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public MainJFrame() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {

which has been working fine but suddenly doesn't work if I add another UI component giving the error above.  But if I delete a component and then add a different one it work fine.  Hence my initial thought about a limited number.